# Delegates to handle any update in 2D array

Tags: c#, delegates

I am writing code to handle any kind of update in my 2D array in C# language.

Supposing I have a 2D array in this format:

```
[1][1][1][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][2][2][0]
[4][4][4][0][0][0]
[0][7][7][7][5][0]
[0][6][0][0][5][0]
[0][6][0][0][5][0]
```

And a Dictionary to keep count of each distinct value in the array.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dict.Add(0,20);
dict.Add(1,3);
dict.Add(2,2);
dict.Add(4,3);
.
.
.
.
```

Now my program updates this 2D array periodically and changes the value of an index. 
I want to track this event and reduce the count of that distinct value in the dictionary. 
So when the program tries to update `array[1,1] = 5;` the dictionary reduces the count of 0 by 1.

Rather than doing the decrements through some other logic, I am thinking of creating a delegate that could do this job for me. But I have very less experience with delegates so just want some help in implementing this.

Comment: A delegate is just a method, and has no specific benefit for you. Why don't you start with a simple approach and build from there?

Comment: You might want to create your own class that contains the array and dictionary and then create indexers and methods on that class for updating the values where you can also update the dictionary.